# Convert the lat and long to address name in MAPBOX GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox, reverse-geocoding

I'm finding it hard to convert the lat and long to an address name in MAPBOX. I have found JavaScript for google api and its fairly straight forward, but i cannot find a solution for mapbbox. Any help is highly appreciated. I know that reverse encoding should be implemented for converting the lat and long to an address, but im so confused after referring to the mapbox reverse geocoding documentation.

At the end of the day, i just want to store the address name of my marker location in a JavaScript variable.

JS

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXNxdWlsYXgiLCJhIjoiY2tqd2ZyMXJsMGVqeDJ4cW8xcnRja2tqdiJ9.7z7Eyrj3iexJ9uDVYIT0yw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location

   center: [lng, lat], 
  
    zoom: 11
    
 
});
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({color:"#ff3300",dragable:true,scale:0.8}).setLngLat([lng, lat]).addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Mapbox Geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/geocoding/), concretely [reverse geocoding](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/#reverse-geocoding). You have to compose your url and refine the results with address as data type Always consider you could get more than one result in the featureCollection response depending your params.

Here you have an example url for the given coords [-73.989, 40.733] which corresponds to 120 East 13th Street, New York, New York 10003, United States:

```js
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/-73.989,40.733.json?types=address&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoianNjYXN0cm8iLCJhIjoiY2s2YzB6Z25kMDVhejNrbXNpcmtjNGtpbiJ9.28ynPf1Y5Q8EyB_moOHylw
```

This will return the following

```json
{"type":"FeatureCollection","query":[-73.989,40.733],"features":[{"id":"address.694032850198644","type":"Feature","place_type":["address"],"relevance":1,"properties":{"accuracy":"rooftop"},"text":"East 13th Street","place_name":"120 East 13th Street, New York, New York 10003, United States","center":[-73.9888929,40.7330031],"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.9888929,40.7330031]},"address":"120","context":[{"id":"neighborhood.2103290","text":"Greenwich Village"},{"id":"postcode.13482670360296810","text":"10003"},{"id":"locality.12696928000137850","wikidata":"Q11299","text":"Manhattan"},{"id":"place.15278078705964500","wikidata":"Q60","text":"New York"},{"id":"region.17349986251855570","wikidata":"Q1384","short_code":"US-NY","text":"New York"},{"id":"country.19678805456372290","wikidata":"Q30","short_code":"us","text":"United States"}]}],"attribution":"NOTICE: © 2021 Mapbox and its suppliers. All rights reserved. Use of this data is subject to the Mapbox Terms of Service (https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/). This response and the information it contains may not be retained. POI(s) provided by Foursquare."}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for answering!! I get the address for your coordinates, But when i change the co ordinates to my values it doesn't return the address :(  My long and lat values were 116.078063888889, -33.8620819444444 . I also tried by swapping them around.  Just to let you know that i get this result when i copy and paste the link into the browser

Comment: I also tried just putting -72 instead of -73 in your coordinates, but it  doesn't work. Seems to only work for that specific coordinates?

Comment: The lnglat location you’re using, corresponds with a road close to Bridgetown in Australia, right? I don’t see any address there.

Comment: But when i use online convertors and put in the lat and long i get an address. But do you think the mapbox API just gives the house address details? Because im trying to provide a location address of a tracking device.  https://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html

Comment: Then try this url, I removed the types=Address filter https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/116.07806,-33.862081.json?&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoianNjYXN0cm8iLCJhIjoiY2s2YzB6Z25kMDVhejNrbXNpcmtjNGtpbiJ9.28ynPf1Y5Q8EyB_moOHylw

Comment: Hey i accepted your answer. But is there a way to extract the address and put it inside a variable. i don't know how to integrate the URL inside the code. If there is a way please show me. Thanks a lot !!!!!

Comment: For that you need to parse the result of the response which is a json. You have to `fetch` the composed url and get the value from the results. Check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Once you `fetch` the url following the examples from developer Mozilla, I think what you are looking for is at `data.features[0].place_name`

Comment: Hey sorry for asking this , but how can i add the variables "lat , long" instead of the numbers inside the fetch url     for example

https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/long,lat.json?&access_token=token

Comment: Are you asking how to concat strings in JavaScript to compose a URL string?

Comment: i have 2 variables called lat and long which contains the value. i just need to replace the numbers in the fetch url and replace it by the variables "lat" and "long". Thank you so much

Comment: `let url = “https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/“ + long + “,” + lat + “.json?&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoianNjYXN0cm8iLCJhIjoiY2s2YzB6Z25kMDVhejNrbXNpcmtjNGtpbiJ9.28ynPf1Y5Q8EyB_moOHylw”;`

Comment: A pleasure to help

Comment: note a random gotcha is the order of the coordinate values... mapbox requires lon,lat in the api call, not lat,lon